# What year would this tricycle be

Tags: identify-this-bike, tricycle

[image]
[image]

The only numbers I got from it were C356635 it’s a Montgomery ward Hawthorne from what it says on the front badge.

Comment: Do you have any higher resolution pictures?

Comment: Pictures of badges/decals would be very useful if any still remain.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. It is nearly impossible to identify a bicycle without high quality pictures. There's no universal schema or centralized database for serial numbers, so they're surprisingly unhelpful Please [edit] some higher resolution photos into your question. Photos of any decals or logos, major components such as cranks and the headtube, and major joints are all very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Given the claim that it is a Montgomery Ward Tricycle.

Hunting through the [Montgomery Ward catalogs](https://christmas.musetechnical.com/) I see a [close match in the 1972 spring / summer catalog](https://christmas.musetechnical.com/ShowCatalogPage/1972-Montgomery-Ward-Spring-Summer-Catalog/0739)

[image]

[By 1981](https://christmas.musetechnical.com/ShowCatalogPage/1981-Montgomery-Ward-Spring-Summer-Catalog/0514) they drop the fenders. In the mid to late 70s they changed the handlebars.

The question is "what year". They sold the same bike several years so it's a range - not a single year. Based on the information given and the information in the catalogue I'd say early 70s.

Comment: Are those dropouts crimped and spot-welded to the stays ?!   That's slightly disconcerting.

Comment: @Criggie that's how many brands of department store bikes were made.

Comment: wow = BSO grade engineering before BSOs were a thing. That's terrifying.